# LDRB in ARM ASM - general questions

Tags: assembly, load, arm

I'm using an ARM architecture and I'm a little unclear on the concept with LDRB. LDRB being LDR with the optional B command, to load the least significant byte of the 32-bit word. Three issues.

1. What I actually want is the first 8 bits, not the last 8 bits (I'm iterating over an array). Is there an elegant way to do this? I couldn't find a command for it.
2. What I'm doing right now is SUB r4, r4, #3 to move r4 (my pointer I want to load) back three bytes so that the least significant byte is now the one in the front of the 32-bit word. Is this liable to cause memory issues if all I do is iterate forward?
3. I'm using LDRB r7, r4; this should load the least significant byte from r4 into r7. By zero extend, it means what'll come out will be something like 00...00010101, or 10101000...00?

Comment: (That is, the ARM documentation says that LDRB will zero extend. It doesn't specify in which direction.)

Comment: `LDRB r7, r4` was not a valid instruction last time I checked. Zero extension means filling up the N _most significant_ bits with zeroes.

Comment: It's a bit unclear how the data you're reading is laid out (e.g. why you need to subtract 3 from your pointers). If a pointer is pointing to the start of a word (i.e. the pointer is word-aligned), then if you `LDRB` from that pointer you'll be reading the least significant byte (on a little-endian machine).

Comment: I'm not sure why LDRB r7, r4 would be invalid; LDR has an optional preface for B and requires a register and a second flexible operand. Why wouldn't that work? Also, I have a char array in C that I need to iterate over byte by byte to check for the 00000000 byte (and save the number of iterations). And since LDRB gives me the least significant byte, I need to start the loop three bytes ahead so that the least significant byte is the start of the array (the most significant byte).

Comment: Ah. Ofc. LDRB r7, [r4];.

Comment: Okay, new plan. `LDRB r7, [r4, #-3], #1;` This shifts the load back 3 bytes, then permanently moves r4 forward, removing any need to iterate it in a separate command. Yay.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't written any ARM assembly in a while, but I don't see how `LDRB r7,[r4, #-3], #1` would work. You can specify _either_ a pre-indexing offset _or_ a post-indexing offset, not both. Also, if your data is a string, it seems to me like the easiest solution would be to just initialize `r4` to point to the first character and then load each character with `ldrb r7,[r4],#1` in a loop. The `ldrb` instruction implicitly zero-extends. If you wanted sign extension you'd have to use `ldrsb`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "first" byte, the "last" byte, and "move to the front". These terms have no real meaning. Please substitute the bit numbers (bits[7:0]) or use terms like "least significant" and "most significant".

Answer (score 6):

If you want the MSB of a 32-bit word, then get the MSB of a 32-bit word:

```
LDR R0, [R1]
LSR R0, #24
```

Anything else is confusing and completely unportable across systems of different endianness - trying to byte address words assuming LE breaks on a BE system. What works on BE-8 breaks if it ever finds itself on an ancient BE-32 system.

In fact, if loading a byte from `[word ptr - #3]` really gives you the MSB rather than the second-least significant byte of the previous word then I think you *are* on a BE-32 system* - thus this won't work correctly on anything modern.

<sub>* or maybe BE-8 - the trickery of memory endianness vs. bus endianness and word vs. byte addressing is massively confusing and I make no claim to have fully grapsed it.</sub>

Comment: Adding to the answer, modern memory systems forces you to fetch multiple bytes - some orders of native word size of the system (native word size is four bytes on ARMv7). Generally memory interface forces core to fetch 32 bytes at least. So if you need to fetch a byte from memory best would be still fetch a word (four bytes) then access the byte you want by shifting. Raison d'être of `LDRB` is to access other hardware components where they require you to have bytewise access since reading from an address could mean something else (like a fifo). So in short don't do LDRB on memory.

Comment: So... Load R1's address into R0, then shift R0 by 24 bits? Wouldn't this cause issues in non-32-bit architectures the same way my code above would? I suppose this probably is the more elegant solution... In my code, it'd be then LDR r7, r4,; LSR r7, #24?

Comment: @JonahStephenSwersey Um, which non-32-bit architectures exactly? AArch64 has a completely different instruction set, exception model, etc. Anything else isn't even ARM...

Comment: See, this is me having no damn clue what I'm talking about. :D